# solution with JAVA or Postgres for insertion in database

Tags: java, postgresql

[image: see this picture]
<sub>(source: [hostingpics.net](http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/152251projet.jpg))</sub>

how can I add a new customer or supplier?, last time I was using this class for one table "customer":

Code:

```
public int addnewcustomer(){
    int idcust;
    DBConnection eConnexion = new DBConnection();
    try {
        //Statement state = eConnexion.getConnexion().createStatement();
        String sql = "INSERT INTO customer(name_cust, num_cust, adress_cust, city_cust , tel_cust, ref_cust)";

        sql+= "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement insertQuery = eConnexion.getConnexion().prepareStatement(sql);
        insertQuery.setString(1,Name_cust);
        insertQuery.setString(2,Num_cust);
        insertQuery.setString(3,Adress_cust);
        insertQuery.setString(4,City_cust );
       insertQuery.setString(5,Tel_cust);
       insertQuery.setString(6,Ref_cust);

       insertQuery.executeUpdate();

} catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Erreur:the addition is not performed with Succee!");
        idcust = 0;
    }
    eConnexion.closeConnection();
    idcust= Services.getLastInsertedId("customer","id_customer");
    return idcust;
}
```

Currently, I attach all tables with new table "person". All tables now extend "person", I tried to add new customer with super variables "person" but I'm stuck in filling foreign key "id_pers FK".

Comment: see this image for diagram class [link](http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/152251projet.jpg)

Comment: you like to insert data into customer/supplier or need to create those tables?

Comment: i created them ,i just need  to insert  customer or supplier or employee

Comment: are you getting error while inserting foreign key? can you check whether the id_pers you are inserting is all available in the "person" table. or pls post the error that you are receiving

Comment: I need the code java or query postgres for filling id_pers FK in table customer while adding new person :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to persist a person into your database. After a successful(!) persist, you can query for the id the database used to insert the data. Most databases also provide a method to directly retrieve the used id after an insert.
After you have successfully persisted the person you can use the id for the foreign key column.

You may consider using a transaction for these actions, as there should never be a person persisted without a customer/employee whatever extending the persons data. 
With a transaction, you can rollback the previous actions, for example if something goes wrong during the insertion of the customer.

Comment: Thank you Mr.Thomas Eizinger for explanation ,Can u help me for this method to retrieve used id after an insert and how I  put the foreign key to customer in JAVA